# Strange Math on first loop in double Foreach

Tags: php

I am doing a foreach inside a foreach, and outputing the data into a div table. everything looks great except the grand total for the very first loop, for some reason I can only get that loop correct if I divide it by 2 but then the rest of the data is off.

I have narrowed it down to be an issue with just 1 variable. `$CM_Total_Earnings` every thing else read correctly but for some reason this one is the one goes wacky only on the first loop.

// edited the code to make it shorter, with more distinct names so others wouldn't have such a hard time following it.

```
        $countrys = \App\Country::all();
        foreach ($countrys as $c) {
            $cid = $c->id;
            $cname = $c->name;

        include 'sub/countryopen.php';  

        $users = App\User::all()->sortBy('type');
        $currency = App\Config::whereKey('currency')->first()->value;

        $Total_msgs_sent = '0';
        $Total_replies = '0';
        $Total_Country_Earnings = '0';
        $Total_Personal_Earnings = '0';
        $CM_Total_Earnings = 0;

        //Start Total Replies
        include 'sub/totalreplies.php';
        //End Total Replies      

        //Start User Table              
        foreach ($users as $u) {
                    $uid = $u->id;
                    $name = $u->name;
                    $type = $u->type;
                    $pay = $u->pay_rate;
                    $countryid = $u->country_id;
                    $ce = $u->ce_rate;

                    $CM_Earnings = '0';          

                    if ( $countryid == $cid ){
                        $role = '';
                        if($type == 'country_manager'){ $role = 'Country Manager'; }
                        if($type == 'team_leader'){ $role = 'Team Leader'; }
                        if($type == 'moderator'){ $role = 'Moderator'; }
                        if($type == 'suspend'){ $role = 'Suspended'; }

                        $sent = '0';
                        $earn = '0';
                        $reply = '0';

                        $total_messages = App\UserSentMessage::select('id','pay_rate')
                            ->where("user_id", "=", $uid )
                            ->get();

                        $count_messages = App\UserSentMessage::select('id')
                            ->where("user_id", "=", $uid )
                            ->where('created_at', '>', $carbon)
                            ->where('created_at', '<', $endcarbon)
                            ->count();

                                $sent = $count_messages;
                                $Total_msgs_sent += $sent;

                                foreach ($total_messages as $msg) {

                                    $rate = $msg->pay_rate; 
                                    if ( $rate == null)
                                        { $rate = $pay; }

                                    $replys = App\UserSentMessageReply::select('id')
                                    ->where("user_sent_message_id", "=", $msg->id )
                                    ->where('created_at', '>', $carbon)
                                    ->where('created_at', '<', $endcarbon)
                                    ->count();

                                    $reply += $replys;  

                                    $replyearn = $replys * $rate;
                                    $earn += $replyearn;


                                }

                                $CM_Earnings = $Total_replies * $ce;
                                $Total_Personal_Earnings += $earn;
                                $CM_Total_Earnings += $CM_Earnings; 

                                if ( $countryid == '1' ) 
                                    {
                                        $CM_Total_Earnings += $CM_Total_Earnings / 2;   
                                    }


                            include 'sub/userinfo.php';
                        }

                    }
        // End User Table


        $Total_Country_Earnings = $Total_Personal_Earnings + $CM_Total_Earnings;
```

You will find `$CM_Total_Earnings` at the bottom.

Comment: Why do you make your totals as a string and then use them in numerical context?

Comment: For a start, you should not initialized a variable that holds a number with a string. Changes all lines looking like `$cmearn = '0'` to `$cmearn = 0`. Another word of advice is to really consider it is worth using DB calls in a loop the way you are doing it. It might bring your server down. You could try using the DB aggregation capabilities. Other than that, what is `$cearn`? Your variable names are not descriptive. That makes it difficult to see what they are meant to be? What is the expected value?

Comment: Instead of outputting CSS style blocks, you could create a CSS class called `noDisplay` in your CSS file and add that class to your HTML elements which should not be displayed.

Comment: You don't always need to declare the variables before use. Some of them for example `$sent = '0'`, `$cmearn = '0';`, `$totalearn = '0';` are declared twice in two different spots

Comment: One word of advice : split this code in several fonctions. I would see at least : one to get the various pieces of data from the database, one to compute stuff from these pieces, one to render the final html

Comment: @Dharman - the variables are needed for those users that are not going through the full loop. it also reset the variable once the loop goes back around zero'ing it out. So, doesn't really matter, Though some of the values do get even worse if you do not use ' ' - so.. thats why

Comment: @asiby why should the be descriptive,  the cearn is the total earnings of the CM which is found first by geting the total replies in the first small top loop for the country, then getting the users CM earning rate. which comes out correctly then the Cearn is the total of all the CMearn values..  but that is what is not coming out correctly ...   it still comes out with a value ..  but its not a correct value.. and only incorrect for the first loop.

Comment: Your statements do not make sense, but that is irrelevant. Start by cleaning up your code. Treat numbers as numbers and strings as strings. Use proper variable names with Pascal Casing or underscores. Then do what @asiby and LeGEC suggested. Move closer to DB and use aggragation and then separate your code into functions.

Comment: Your example variables could be named: `$CM_earnings;` and `$total_CM_earnings;`, but whatever you decide to name them they should not be acronyms or 1 letter names. Trust me you will not remember what they mean after 1 year.

Comment: @N8Core, no offence, but someone would have solved your question by now if the code was super clear. Keep in mind that as much as source codes are meant for computers, it is even more important that they are easy to understand by human. This helps others debug your code when needed. And if you move on to another job, whoever replaces you will not have to feel like a cryptologist when reading your source code.

Comment: @Dharman yea, but none of this has anything to do with the issue.

Comment: @asiby LOL I do not have to worry about that.  but - I just notice that if i adjust the number of CM users from the 1st country then it multiples the $cearn with 3 CM's i had to divide it by 2 to get the correct total then with only 2 CM's it had to be divded by 4... the other countries in the loop after the first one does not have this problem with their total..

Comment: (INT)$CM_Total_Earnings

Comment: What is in `sub/totalreplies.php` and `sub/countryopen.php`? Since you are including those files, their content will be part of the scope of the part of the code we are seeing. It could be relevant.